# how to modify date in php if data is not found for current date?

Tags: php

I have a $date variable that check if that date has program and now I want that if data is not found for that date then it should check for previous date i.e. i want to decrement my date each time.

how can i modify $date to a previous date in a php function if data not found for current date in table

Comment: `$date = strtotime('-1 day');`

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Comment: Seems like a database-related question, although it's difficult to understand what's being asked here...

Comment: If you need a max date from table you can use query `select max(columnDate) from table`